# mail_form gem rspec "undefined method `email' for"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mail-form

how can I write a test mail_form gem?
Вut the test gives an error.
How to associate a OrderForm and MailForm?
I have :
model:

```
class OrderForm < MailForm::Base
  attributes :name
  attributes :email
  attributes :phone_number
  attributes :order_name
  attributes :address
  attributes :file_1, attachment: true
  def mail_attachments
    [:file_1]
  end
```

controller, where:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @order_form = OrderForm.new(params[:order_form])
    @order_form.deliver
    redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Заявка отправлена'
  end
end
```

end view(form of sending a letter):
orders/new.html.haml_spec.rb

```
   =form_for @order_form, url: orders_path, method: :post do |f|
         =f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'ФИО', class: 'gui-input'
         =f.text_field :email, placeholder: 'Email', class: 'gui-input'
         =f.text_field :phone_number, placeholder: 'Номер телефона',
```

end I write test:

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe "orders/new", type: :view do
    it do
        assign(:order, build(:order))
        render
      expect(rendered).to have_field :name
    end
end
```

Comment: and, a have message error:
orders/new 
     Failure/Error: =form_for @order_form, url: orders_path, method: :post do |f|
     
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Answer (score 1):

check the output of `rake routes`, url `orders/new` will execute the `orders#new` action and render the view `orders/new.html.erb`

```
GET /orders/new orders#new  return an HTML form for creating a new order
```

`new.html.erb` will use the variables from your `orders#new` action. You are missing those variables

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def new 
    @order_form = OrderForm.new
  end

  def create
    @order_form = OrderForm.new(params[:order_form])
    @order_form.deliver
    redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Заявка отправлена'
  end
end
```

Comment: I have url orders/new, and orders#new action, and other actions (send_message, show etc).rendered the views - ok.
I have the problem with rspec test:
I have message error:
orders/new 
     Failure/Error: =f.text_field :email, placeholder: 'Email', class: 'gui-input'
     
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `email' for #<Order:0x007f9f9f0c6b60>

Comment: @AleksZadkov `OrderForm` has the `email` attribute. You don't have the email attribute for `Order`. All your architecture is wrong.. You don't create an orderform object. read the guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html and try to understand the concept of http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html